# File is not checked out Exception in Publishing Page with WebParts

Tags: web-part, publishing, exception

I have a problem with Sharepoint 2010.

When I **edit a publishing** page (checked in) **without webparts**:

1 - (Checked out the page automatically)

2 - It's all OK I can edit the page.

When I **edit a publishing** page (checked in) **with webparts**:

It crashes! :(

"*Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException:File is not checked out*".

Can you help me?

*Kind regards*

Answer (score 0):

To edit the page, first you must check out the page. This is only thing you need to consider before editing.

Comment: Thanks, but...Why with the pages without webparts, check out automatically?

Comment: I have checked on my server for your both scenarios, there were no error at all, instead for second scenario it has automatically checked out the page and worked for me. Have you changed anything on master page or page layout?